# Чтение qr-кода веб-камерой на сайте средствами Java

Tags: java

Ребята, идея такова: будет некий сайт, при входе на который запускается веб-камера, считывает qr-код и отправляет информацию в БД, там сохраняется, обрабатывается, ну и всё в таком духе. Реализовать это всё я хочу на Java в качестве своего проекта, дабы потрогать все эти jsp, сервелеты, jdbc. Собственно, особого недостатка в информации нет — бери и делай, НО как реализовать чтения qr-кода, я вообще не пойму. Гугл насилую битый час — информации никакой, кроме той, где идёт работа напрямую с веб-камерой, но это вроде-бы не совсем то, что нужно, потому что не вяжется с той концепцией, где веб-камера будет запускать на сайте.

Answer (score 1):

С вебкамерой должен работать клиент, а не сервер.